# Get item from local storage and use it in html page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I used javascript to save username information in local storage, so that when the user logs in, the username appears in the profile page. My problem is that I don't know how to get the username from the local storage and write it in my html page.
So far I have this:

```
function user(){

  document.write(localStorage.getItem("name1");
}
```

This code is not working and I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: is user who logged in are saved?

Comment: The user information is saved in local storage.

Comment: Is there any error in the console

Comment: Turns out I wasn't closing the parentheses, but now I get a white page with the uername on it, but it replaced the html

Comment: I need it to write in the existing html inside a div

Comment: document.write(localStorage.getItem("name1"); need put one more ")", you just wrote wrong at hear, or into your code realy is withou the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the value to an existing HTML element, e.g.

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name1");
```

HTML should in such a case contain an element with ID test:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

You might first want to check if the key actually exist though, like so:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("name1") != null) {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name1");
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed,

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe could help.

```
function getUser(){
    name = localStorage.getItem("name");
    if (name == null || name == "null"){
      alert("Howdy, Stranger!");
      name = prompt("Who are you?");
      localStorage.setItem("name", name);
    } else {
      alert ("Hi, " + name + "!");
    } // end getUser
  } // end function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof (localStorage.getItem("name1")) != null && (localStorage.length != 0)) {
var name1= localStorage.getItem("name1");
}
else {
alert("local storage kills");
}
```

The above code will be useful for you..